# How to create table with Foreign Keys in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a `users` table

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

and a `roles` table

```php
Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id('role_id');
    $table->string('role_name');
});
```

Now I want to create a `user_role` table which have two foreign keys

```php
Schema::create('user_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->foreign('role_id')->references('role_id')->on('roles');
});
```

But I'm getting an error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') default
> character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'' at line 1 (SQL:
> create table `user_role` () default character set utf8mb4 collate
> 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the field and add a foreign key to it directly by using `foreignIdFor()`. This creates a column `UNSIGNED BIGINT` and adds a foreign key to the parent table.

```php
Schema::create('user_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreignIdFor(\App\Models\User::class);
    $table->foreignIdFor(\App\Models\Role::class);
});
```

Under the hood, this is how the `foreginIdFor` and `foreginId` methods looks like. As you can see, it attaches the foreign key by the primary key type of the model you're using.

```
/**
 * Create a new unsigned big integer (8-byte) column on the table.
 *
 * @param  string  $column
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Schema\ForeignIdColumnDefinition
 */
public function foreignId($column)
{
    $this->columns[] = $column = new ForeignIdColumnDefinition($this, [
        'type' => 'bigInteger',
        'name' => $column,
        'autoIncrement' => false,
        'unsigned' => true,
    ]);

    return $column;
}

/**
 * Create a foreign ID column for the given model.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|string  $model
 * @param  string|null  $column
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Schema\ForeignIdColumnDefinition
 */
public function foreignIdFor($model, $column = null)
{
    if (is_string($model)) {
        $model = new $model;
    }

    return $model->getKeyType() === 'int' && $model->getIncrementing()
                ? $this->foreignId($column ?: $model->getForeignKey())
                : $this->foreignUuid($column ?: $model->getForeignKey());
}
```

Comment: Attention! This won't create the foreign key. Just the column. You have to do foreignIdFor(...)->constrained();

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your foreign key id fields to your joining table:

```
Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->foreignId('user_id);
  $table->foreignId('role_id');

  $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
  $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
});
```

Change the name of your `id` field in your `roles` table to just `id`. No need for the prefix.

```
Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->id('id');
  $table->string('role_name');
});
```

Also, the convention is to name your joining table alphabetically; so notice I changed the above to be `role_user`.

Comment: It worked! also didn't know about this naming convention. Thank you!

Comment: @jade Check out the [Laravel from Scratch](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-6-from-scratch) series on Laracasts. A lot of it is still relevant for Laravel 8 including eloquent relationships, conventions and more. Plus it is free! [:

Answer (score 0):

```
Schema::create('user_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
   
        $table->integer('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

        $table->integer('role_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('role_id')->on('roles');

    });
```